# $f$ differentiable, $c\in(a,b)$ $\Rightarrow \exists x_1,x_2$, $a\leq x_1<x_2\leq b$ : $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I've been trying to prove or disprove the following statement:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and differentiable  on $(a,b)$, and let $c\in(a,b)$. Then there exist $x_1, x_2$ such that $a\leq x1<x_2\leq b$ and $f'(c)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$.

Something seems pretty odd here. At first I thought it was just a manipulation of the Mean Value Theorem, but then I saw the difference ("there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$" instead of "there exists $c$"). I tried to think whether this makes the statement wrong or not, but I couldn't think of a counterexample. Of course, the statement might be true.

Thanks!

Comment: Should $c\in (x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Nope, $c\in (a,b)$ as mentioned

Comment: @TitoEliatron Oh, I think I understand. Injective function does the trick. Thanks!